# How to parse week and year with strptime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Usually I don't have issues parsing strings to Time in Rails, however I cannot understand why it's behaving like this:

```rb
irb(main):073:0> DateTime.strptime("20/2020", "%V/%Y")
=> Wed, 01 Jan 2020 00:00:00 +0000
```

I want the 20th week of 2020, not the 1st Jan...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use the [`commercial`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial) method.

```
require 'date'

week = 20
start_week = Date.commercial(2020, week)
# => Mon, 11 May 2020

puts "#{start_week}"
# => 2020-05-11
```

In case  you need a Range, you can do:

```
Date.commercial(2020, week).all_week
# => Mon, 11 May 2020..Sun, 17 May 2020
```

For more information see the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'
```

If week 1 begins on Sunday:

```
Date.strptime("20/2020", "%U/%Y")
  #=> #<Date: 2020-05-17 ((2458987j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

and on Monday:

```
d = Date.strptime("20/2020", "%W/%Y")
  #=> #<Date: 2020-05-18 ((2458988j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

and also from the doc [Date#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) (which contains the formatting directives for [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime)), "The days in the year before the first week are in week `0`".

Answer (score 0):

There is generally a difference between `%Y` and `%G` for the year depending on your assumed definition for a week number.

For ISO 8601 weeks (which are commonly used in e.g. Europe), you have to use the week-based year here (`%G`) rather than the day-=based year (`%Y`). This is important around the edges of the years. For example, 2021-01-01 is in week 53 of 2020. On this date

- `%G` is `2020`, but
- `%Y` is already `2021`

If you want to parse an ISO 8601 week, you can thus use the following code to ensur you use the right week and year:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime("20/2020", "%V/%G")
# => #<DateTime: 2020-05-11T00:00:00+00:00 ((2458981j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```